# Visual Basic (Excel) Run 2 Macros through 1 button?

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a button to export my spreadsheet to PDF.

I wish to have that button export the document and save it in a folder called "Excel Calculator". Currently I can only get a folder to be created or the document to be exported. I am not sure how to run both commands at once so the document exports and is saved in the excel calculator folder.

Also, how can I change the file path so instead of going into D:\ like I have specified, it finds the users "My Documents" folder.

```
Sub GetFilenameForPDF()
 Dim strFileName As String, strB1 As String, strWorksheet As String


 strB1 = Range("B1").Value
 strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
 strFileName = strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")


End Sub

Sub NewFolder()

 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Dim folderName As String

 Set fso = New FileSystemObject
 folderName = "D:\Excel Calculator"
 If fso.FolderExists(folderName) = False Then
     fso.CreateFolder folderName
 End If

 Dim strFileName As String, strB1 As String, strWorksheet As String
 strB1 = Range("B1").Value
 strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
 strFileName = folderName + "\" + strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & 
 Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     "D:\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
 End Sub

 Sub SaveToPDF()

 Dim strFileName As String, strB1 As String, strWorksheet As String
 strB1 = Range("B1").Value
 strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
 strFileName = strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     "D:\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
     :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call several macros sequentially. For example, if you link your button to the macro `fullSequence`, then you can run first the creation of the folder and then the export of the file into that folder:

```
Sub fullSequence()
    createFolder '<-- call macro 1
    exportFile '<-- call macro 2
End Sub
```

In your specific case, you just need to modify the code of the macro `NewFolder` from this:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     "D:\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

... to this:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     folderName & "\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

... in order to include `folderName` (where you already have your folder path) into the export `Filename` parameter.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply

I added the `full sequence` sub and changed the names of the `SaveToPDF()` and `NewFolder` subs to match the macros being called in `full sequence`

However, now when I link the macro to the button I get the error: "System Error &H8007007B (-2147024773)"